# Redirect to previous URL after login using Revel

Tags: authentication, revel

I have a golang web application made with revel framework. I am facing issue in redirecting to the previous page after login. I have few pages where users should login to view the content. I have successfully redirected to login page if the users is not logged in. Here is my code snippet below:

```golang
func checkUser(c *revel.Controller) revel.Result {
if _, ok := c.Session["user"]; ok {
    return nil
}
  var cont = c.Request.RequestURI
  fmt.Printf("Requesting URL : ", cont)
  return c.Redirect(LoginApp.Login, cont)
}

func init() {
  revel.InterceptFunc(checkUser, revel.BEFORE, &App{})
}
```

And here is my app.go

```golang
type App struct {
  *revel.Controller
}

func (c App) Application() revel.Result {
  var app = make(map[string]string)
  app["appTitle"] = "Hourglass"
  app["ngApp"] = "app"
  app["theme"] = "dark"
  app["ngController"] = "ApplicationController"
  return c.Render(app)
}

func (c App) Test() revel.Result {
  var app = make(map[string]string)
  app["appTitle"] = "Hourglass"
  app["ngApp"] = "app"
  app["theme"] = "dark"
  app["ngController"] = "ApplicationController"
  return c.Render(app)
}
```

Now I have a login.go file which contains a **ServiceLogin** method

```golang
func (c LoginApp) ServiceLogin(user models.User) revel.Result {

  username := user.UserName
  password := user.Password
  fmt.Printf("", username)
  fmt.Printf("", password)
  sess := service.GetSession()
  usercoll := sess.DB("hourglass_dev").C("user")
  var result models.User
  var err = usercoll.Find(bson.M{"UserName": username, "Password":   password}).One(&result)
  fmt.Printf("", result)
  fmt.Printf("", c.Request.RequestURI)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("", err)
  }
  //var app := make(map[string]string)
  //return c.Render(app)
  c.Session["user"] = username
  return c.Redirect(App.Application)
}
```

Now in the last line of the method I have to hard coded the **App.Application** instead of which I want the requesting URL to be used so that when the user logged in successfully it automatically redirects to the page they are requesting for.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do:

- You could use the [referer field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) of the header in the request and redirect back there. I don't know how reliable the referer field is so I don't think I would use this technique myself, but it's easy, so depending on your use-case, it might be good enough. In revel, you would access the referer with something like this:

  ```
  c.Request.Header["referer"].Get()
  ```
- You could store the original link you want to redirect to in the database, and associate that link with the session id you are already using. Revel does not come with a database, but it does come with an in-memory cache that might work.
- You could store the link in a cookie on the client. I never do this, so I'm not really sure what you need to think about with this, but I believe it would work.
- You could communicate the link to each URL in the process via request parameters. There's a few things to keep in mind with this technique including security, url escaping and so on, but this technique has some advantages, such as not requiring database access. Your URLs would look something like this:

  ```
  http://www.example.com/loginurl?redirecturl=[someurl]
  ```